# How does PIL getbbox method work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to understand the [PIL getbbox](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox) (get boundary box) function, which "Calculates the bounding box of the non-zero regions in the image."

In the following code, I use getbbox and it returns exactly what I expect it to with simple grayscale images.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance,ImageChops
import PIL

def trim(im):
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, im.getpixel((0,0)))

diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
bbox = diff.getbbox() 

#None if getbbox returns None
if bbox:
     return im.crop(bbox)
```

I don't however understand how it works accord to its [source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L1170). Besides the self.load(), it seems to do some sort of recursive call on itself. I thought recursive functions needed terminating conditions, but I see none?

I feel like it has something to do with somehow removing the black pixels in the image array, but I just don't understand these seemingly cryptic 2 lines of code (below). Any help in me understanding this would be appreciated.

```
def getbbox(self):
    """
    Calculates the bounding box of the non-zero regions in the
    image.
    :returns: The bounding box is returned as a 4-tuple defining the
       left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate. If the image
       is completely empty, this method returns None.
    """

    self.load()
    return self.im.getbbox()
```

edit: pasted in source code

Comment: There is no recursion here; `self.im` is an entirely different object than `self`.

Comment: @jasonharper sorry to bother I am very new at python, how does Image call im ?

Comment: @jasonharper think I got it   im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix, formats) (line 3007 Image.py)

Answer (score 1):

As has been commented, this is not recursion. im.getbbox() calls https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/_imaging.c#L1947

That then calls ImagingGetBBox - https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/libImaging/GetBBox.c#L24